# Graphs and probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory

I was given the next question:

Given that I have an infinite graph of the natural numbers as its vertices and the fact that for two vertices there is a probability of $0.5$ that they have an edge between them. I was asked to find the probability that the graph is connected (the graph is undirected).

My question is how do I approach this type of question? I tried looking at a smaller portion of a set of numbers yet I feel kind of lost. Any clues will be very helpful! I'd really like a clue instead of answering the question right away! Thank you very much.

Comment: As a suggestion, take two vertices $A,B$.  What is the probability that they both connect to $1$? $2$?  etc. (ignore the cases where the common point would coincide with one or the other).  What is the probability that there is no node to which they both connect?

Comment: Hey lulu! the entire graph is of the natural numbers, so in your suggestion A and B are naturals right?

Comment: This might interest you: your description gives the [Rado graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph) (also known as *the* random graph).

Comment: Yes.  Take $A=1,B=2$ just to be specific.

Comment: @lulu So the probability that any two given vertices are connected is $1$. However, this must be checked for infinitely many vertices. So the probability that the graph is connected has a $1^\infty$ form, and this is thus not _entirely_ as obvious as you make it seem

Comment: @Arthur  Yes, I'm just coming to that conclusion.  In fact, at the moment I'm more inclined to think it isn't connected (but intuition is hard to come by).

Comment: @lulu At any rate, clearly this is a tail event so the probability is either $0$ or $1$. That should at least narrow it down a bit ^^

Comment: What do you mean by a tail event @Arthur ?

Comment: @Lola A tail event is something that occurs when you look at the final result of infinitely many events. If the probability of whatever you're looking for is independent of what happens the first finitely many steps, then what you are looking for is called a tail event. Those are known to [have probability either $0$ or $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero–one_law). A more known example of a tail event is whether, in the decimal expansion of a random real number, each finite sequence of digits appears at least once.

Comment: @Arthur but it can't be 1 in this case, right? Because there are a lot of cases where we don't result in a connective graph

Comment: @Lola Careful: Probability $0$ does _not_ mean impossible. It just means very improbable. Among all these possible random graphs, the theorem I refered to above says that either the connected graphs vastly outnumnber the disconnected ones, or the disconnected ones vastly outnumber the connected ones (in some meaningful sense of "outnumber", since there are infinitely many of each). The question now is, which is true? I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: http://keithbriggs.info/documents/connectivity-Manchester2004Nov19.pdf this may answer part of your question

Comment: @BGM we haven't discussed  Bernoulli  yet in class

Comment: @Lola This problem seems to be really tough given your set of tools. Maybe your teacher is satisfied by lulu's reasoning.

Comment: @M.Winter the last subject we've discussed in class was "Conditional probability", does this have anything to do with lulu's comment?

Comment: @Lola Hm, not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give you a proof or a hint, but a reference. As I noted in a comment, your construction yields with probability one the so called [*Rado graph*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph) (Yes, even if it seems to be a random process, it almost surely yields $-$ up to isomorphism $-$ only a *single* graph. Amazing, isn't it?).

Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph#Related_concepts) (somewhere in the linked section)

> The Rado graph has diameter two [...]

and gives two references. This implies that it is connected (seemingly by lulu's initial reasoning). And this implies that your process yields a connected graph with probability one. I think this might help you to find an answer because now you at least know what you are looking for.

---

Further in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G.28n.2C_p.29) section of the Wikipedia article on your random graph model (it got the scary name *Erdős–Rényi model*), there is implied the following (warning: not completely rigorous):

> Given a random graph $G_n$ on $n$ vertices and probability $p_n$ for any edge. If we have
>   $$p_n>\frac{(1+\epsilon)\ln n}n,$$
>   then in the limit $n\to\infty$ the random graph $G_n$ will be connected (with probability one).

Because $\ln n/n\to0$ for $n\to\infty$ but $p_n=1/2$, I take this as another hint that the Rado graph is connected. It seems you need quite some advanced mathematics to solve this problem rigorously.